# storing tons of different variables over time into one variable in SQL Db

Tags: php, mysql

Alright,

I have a column like this

|Name | Orders |

Kevin / numbers

Now on my form whenever I make a new order for Kevin and I make the Order number for instance 1234. I want it to store 1234 into the variable numbers so It can be saved into the DB.

Then I would like to just pull out the variable numbers and be able to see all the order numbers in that array.

so Numbers might right now only equal this

$numbers = '1234';

Eventually it might equal this though

$numbers = '123' . '324' . '434' . '232';

and so on..

Also the variable $numbers is Unique per user so Kevin $numbers variable will be different the Johns $numbers variable and so on....

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I couldn't quite understand your question. BUT, I'm taking a wild guess here and say that your database structure seems wrong. I think you shouldn't store the `order` on `Kevin`, you should store `Kevin` on the `orders`.

Comment: You seem not to understand basics of databases, show us some of your code

Comment: Im sorry, Im trying to figure out a easy way for storing and retrieving multiple order numbers per person... Like if User KEVIN is in my DB I dont wanna just know how many orders he has.. I wanna know which orders belong to Kevin

Comment: Don't store them that way. Just add a new row for the name with the new number. In the future you will want to search your table and it will cause you issues in that format

Comment: @FirstOne I am such a dummy.. Your right.. I need to make a new table just for orders and on completing a order form have it store Kevin as the customer under the Table orders..... Man thanks lol

Answer (score 2):

You are facing a classic problem that makes people turn to a relational database model. 
I would suggest having 2 seperate tables: `Person` and `Order`

And relate these tables together using IDs

**Person** (columns)

```
| id | name | info | ...|
```

**Order** (columns)

```
| id | person_id | order_info |
```

Now you can relate these together using: `Person.id` = `Order.person_id`

A person "Frank" will have one entry in Person table with a unique id, and all of Frank's orders will be in the Order table with his unique id as the person_id.

Of course there are other ways to do this, but this is a simple relational model to accomplish your task.